# Get input file path using NeutralinoJS

Tags: javascript, html, neutralinojs

How do I get input file path using NeutralinoJS?

My Code:

```html
<input type="file" id="inputFile">
```

```js
const inputFilePath = document.getElementById('inputFile').files[0].path
console.log(inputFilePath)
```

Comment: For security reasons browsers don't allow you to access or read file paths client-side.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think browsers allow you to get file paths.

You could use the file picker API instead `os.showDialogOpen(DialogOpenOptions)`:
https://neutralino.js.org/docs/api/os#osshowdialogopendialogopenoptions

```html
<button onclick="onFileUpload()">
```

```js
async onFileUpload () {
  let response = await Neutralino.os.showDialogOpen({
    title: 'Select a file'
  })
  console.log(`You've selected: ${response.selectedEntry}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the path? If you need the content from the upload file you can get it via javascript filereader API and use the contents.
If you need the file for later use you can read the file via js filereader and then create and save a new file with `filesystem.writeFile(WriteFileOptions)` to your prefered location (maybe app internal temp path). Be sure the destination path exists. For that you can use `filesystem.createDirectory(CreateDirectoryOptions)`.

Example with jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).on('change','#myUpload',function(){ //Click on file input
  if(jQuery(this).val().length > 0){ //Check if a file was chosen
    let input_file = this.files[0];
    let file_name = input_file.name;
    let fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e) {
        fileCont = e.target.result;
        //Do something with file content
        saveMyFile(file_name, fileCont); //execute async function to save file
    };
    fr.readAsText(input_file);
  }
});

async function saveMyFile(myFileName, myFileContent){
    await Neutralino.filesystem.createDirectory({ path: './myDestPath' }).then(data => { console.log("Path created."); },() => { console.log("Path already exists."); }); //create path if it does not exist
    //write the file:
    await Neutralino.filesystem.writeFile({
        fileName: './myDestPath/' + myFileName,
        data: myFileContent
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Neutralino.os` API for showing the Open/Save File Dialogs.

This is A Example For Opening A File.

HTML:

```html
<button type="button" id="inputFile">Open File</button>
```

JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("inputFile").addEventListener("click", openFile);

async function openFile() {
  let entries = await Neutralino.os.showOpenDialog('Save your diagram', {
    filters: [
      {name: 'Images', extensions: ['jpg', 'png']},
      {name: 'All files', extensions: ['*']}
    ]
  });
  console.log('You have selected:', entries);
}
```